# cp -u is illegal on mac. What are the alternatives?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, osx-lion

I have a MacbookPro Lion, and I have tried to archive my files that is tried to copy and overwrite if the source is newer than the destination. I tried the following command

```
cp -u source destination
```

but it says, -u is illegal. I also did not find --update or -u in the `man cp`.

Can you please help, what can I do in this situation?

[I have the question moved over here from SO, so feel free to answer it once more. I hope this is the right way of dealing with this]

Comment: Install GNU Coreutils.

Comment: Any love for `rsync`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to use [rsync](http://ss64.com/osx/rsync.html). It is a backup application that can do what `cp -u` does (and much, much more).

The basic usage would be something like :

```
rsync -u source destination
```

However, you really should check out the man page because there are **MANY** useful options.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-nt` condition:

```
[[ source/$file -nt destination/$file ]] && cp source/$file destination/$file
```

Just run this for all files (via a loop or through `find`).

Answer (score 3):

I have installed GNU Coreutils with MacPorts by

```
sudo ports install coreutils findutils
```

findutils are not necessary but [they suggested to install it too](http://www.sgenomics.org/~jtang/blog/posts/Enabling_the_gnu_coreutils_and_findutils_with_macports_on_OSX/).

I followed the idea from Keith Thompson, (kudos!). It works greatly, the "advanced" copy command is now:

```
/opt/local/libexec/gnubin/cp
```

It does not have a man page, but has a long, man-style help with the `--help` option.

Comment: I reassociated this question with your account, so you should be able to comment, accept answers, etc.

Comment: If you use zsh this will override highlighting. But it is still awesome.